# Cassandra cqlsh connecton and data insertion through copy command?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I am having a single datacenter with 5 node cassandra cluster up and running. I have created a keyspace with RF=3 and with simple strategy. I need a clarity on below points-

1. With nodetool getpoints tells on which node our data got physically stored. So i get to know that my data is stored on node-2,3,4. But still i can see the respective sstable and *.db files on each node. So if data is physically stored at node-2,3,4 then why it is showing on node-0,1 as well??
2. After connecting through cqlsh client, consistency command showing me ONE as a default consistency level. So my understanding is now if i will perform any read or write through copy command will be executed as consistency ONE. So if i will make three or four node down at a time except a node from 2,3,4, will it have any impact on client connection (cassandra read or write query)??

Please let me know on this to get a better clarity on understanding cassandra concepts??

Answer (score 1):

1. Cassandra distributes data to all nodes of the cluster based on the hash value of specific partition key (this has value is often called **token**) and number of replicas, so PK with value 1 will be on nodes (3,4,5), with value 2 on the nodes (5, 1, 2), etc.  The `nodetool getendpoints` gives you location of the rows with specific partition key, not for all data.  You can read more about it in the following [blog post](http://www.luketillman.com/one-token-ring-to-rule-them-all/).
2. CL `ONE` means that we need confirmation of read or write operation only from one replica of the data (you have three replicas because of RF=3).  Writes are always sent to all replicas, but we confirm operation if only one answers with success.  For your specific question - in your case you can tolerate loss of the 2 nodes that are responsible for specific partition key.

I recommend to read at least first parts of the Cassandra: The Definitive Guide, 3rd edition - it's [freely available](https://www.datastax.com/resources/ebook/oreilly-cassandra-definitive-guide) from DataStax.  Or read [DataStax Enterprise Architecture Guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-arch/index.html) - it covers Cassandra's architecture as well.

P.S. I recommend to use [DSBulk utility](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html) instead of using the copy command - it's heavily optimized for performance when loading or unloading the data (especially for big amounts of data), and much more flexible.

Comment: Thanks Alex!! Still coming to question-1, once we create the table with partitioning key and get to know that its data stored at node(3,4,5) and when i am querying this table by making any one node(3,4,5) down, client connection got terminated..as mentioned i am querying table with consistency 1. Error : not enough replica available for query at consistency ONE(1 required but only 0 alive). It,s SSL enabled cluster. Let me know what's going wrong here.

Comment: if you're doing this from `cqlsh`, then it's how it works - it connects only to provided node, and work via it. In application, driver should handle re-rerouting automatically.  You also can enable automatic retries in the driver, to avoid such things

Comment: Thanks!! I am connected through external cqlsh client, able to figure out the issue. Much appreciated your response and time.